# how to print the clipboard (which file its contains)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, wxwidgets, clipboard, pywin32

I want to print clipboard contain by this program.
Instade of printing given output I want to print clipboard..

```
def GetTextFromClipboard(self):
        """
        """
        clipboard = wx.Clipboard()
        if clipboard.Open():
            if clipboard.IsSupported(wx.DataFormat(wx.DF_FILENAME)):
                data = wx.FileDataObject()
                clipboard.GetData(data)
                s = data.GetText()
                self.tc.AppendText("Clip content:\n%s\n\n" % s )

                clipboard.Close()
            else:
                self.tc.AppendText("")
```

Comment: It's very confusing that you keep editing your question changing the code significantly without even mentioning it, as it makes the existing answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to copy the *path* of the file on clipboard and not the *text* which is there. In this case you need to use `wx.DF_FILENAME` instead of `wx.DF_TEXT` and `wxFileDataObject` that you currently use.

Comment: Yes those two lines are wrong..  ex. When we copy something in computer (A.Txt) at that time clipboard stores the address of that variable " C:\program files\A.txt " I want to copy this path from clipboard

Comment: You still didn't answer what exactly doesn't work for you.

Comment: This program is printing "clip content changed" when I copy something instade of that I want "path" (I want to see which file I copied)

Comment: OK, I think I finally may have a hint of what you're trying to do, so I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Error: 'FileDataObject' object has no attribute 'GetText'

Comment: You really need to read the documentation to find the names of the methods to use, you can't expect others to write your code for you without understanding at all what you're doing.

Comment: Still not getting result